# How to read in an r session a pdf file protected by password - tm package

Tags: r, pdf, tm

I'm trying to read a pdf document protected by a password in my r session
using the function Corpus() from the tm package.

I was able to do it with the pdf_text function of pdftools using the following code

```r
df <- pdftools::pdf_text(path_to_pdf,upw = "pwd")
```

My question would really be where do I put the "password" argument in the Corpus() function?
Any suggestions would be of great help

Comment: Why don't you use both packages? `pdftools` to read the text from the password protected file, and `tm` to do your text mining on that text. You can feed the raw text into the `tm` package.

Comment: Thank for your comment cory. I've already tried something similar: I've passed my df to the VCorpus function, but it throw an error every time.